# Datatable Scroller plugin issue with Lightning (AJax)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, jquery, datatable

I am trying to render my Datatable with Scroller plugin in. Data is loading once but when scrolled further shows loading data only. Am I missing something ? I am trying to implement it in Salesforce Lightning

```
     sessionTable = $j('#table-1').DataTable(
   {
 "info": true,
 "searching": true,
// destroy : true,
 "processing": false,
 "dom": '<"div-pg"pi><"div-search"f><"div-tbl">t<"bottom-info"> ', // f search, p :- pagination , l:- page length
 //"data": '',
  paging:true,
 "order" : [[2,"asc"]],
 "serverSide": true,

 //scrollY: "200px",
 scrollX : true,
 "ajax": function (data, callback, settings) {
              var allRecs = component.get("c.runQuery");

             console.log('Here in AJAX');
              allRecs.setParams(
              {
                 "request" : data ,
              });

                 allRecs.setCallback(this, function(response)
                 {
                    console.log('in setCallback Populating Data' );
                    /*console.log(response.getReturnValue());*/

                    var state = response.getState();

                     if(state === 'SUCCESS' && response.getReturnValue != null)
                     {
                         //callback(JSON.parse(response.getReturnValue()));
                        //callback(sessionTable.rows.add(JSON.parse(response.getReturnValue())).columns.adjust().draw());

                         var resp = JSON.parse(response.getReturnValue());
                         console.log(resp);

                         setTimeout( function () {
                         callback( {
                             draw:resp.draw,
                             data: JSON.parse(resp.data),
                             recordsTotal: resp.recordsTotal,
                             recordsFiltered: resp.recordsTotal
                         } );
                              }, 200 );



                 });
                 $A.enqueueAction(allRecs);
     },


 scrollY:     "300px",
 scroller: {
     loadingIndicator: true
 },
 scrollCollapse: true,

 "language":
 {
     "emptyTable": "Loading Data"
 },
```

Comment: have you tried any debugging at all? stating a description of your problem and dumping your code is not really the best approach for getting help. Additionally, if you are developing in lightning, there are several architectural considerations you should be aware about -> [Locker service](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2016/04/introducing-lockerservice-lightning-components.html). Take some time to review [ask] and take the [tour] to get familiar with the forum, thanks!

Comment: May i know what you found wrong in this question ? I have been trying to work on the issue from past 2 days. Did lot of debugging. Locker service supports the version of jQuery and Datatable I am using.

Comment: for starters, you did not include any debugging details in your post

Comment: Debugging Details :- As soon as i scroll down AJAX Should be called which is getting called there is no callback from APEX Controller.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with Salesforce Lightning, it was not returning the response. Here is walkaround for this, we can force Salesforce to give response by adding following code after enqueuing:-

```
$A.enqueueAction(allRecs); 
window.setTimeout(
$A.getCallback(function() {
    console.log('Calling');                                     
}), 200);
```